# Modify subject line of cronjob

Tags: command-line, cron, email

I have the following one-line `cron` command set up which gives me a nice simple message in the body of the email upon backup complete (thanks to @steeldriver).

```
tar -cpzf /home/user/backups/backup_files.tar.gz /home/user/public_html;
case $? in 0) echo "Files successfully backed up at $(date)" ;; *) echo "Backup failed" ;; esac
```

The issue is that the whole command line is output into the subject line of my email. This is not ideal as it gives the entire path to my backups across email. I'd prefer the subject to just say something simple like, "Backup user"

Is there a way to do this without upsetting the existing command? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the default `cron` mail subsystem; you can declare your own. Create a single one-line `cron` entry containing this (which I've split over three lines for increased readability).

```
if tar czf /home/user/backups/backup_files.tar.gz -C / home/user/public_html;
then echo "Files successfully backed up at $(date)";
else echo 'Backup failed'; fi | mail -s 'Backup user' root
```

Some notes

- I've removed the `-p` flag from `tar` since it's ignored when you're create an archive
- I've added the `-C` flag to change directory so that the backup source is a relative file (which in turn stops the `` tar: Removing leading `/' from member names `` warning message)
- I've provided `root` to take your user account's local email, but if your system is set up to handle network email you could replace that with any reachable address
- Personally, I'd put it in a script and call the script from `cron`. This allows your script to be laid out more readably, and you can add necessary complexity (sophistication!) as required without hitting `cron` line limits and other surprises.

Comment: Yes, once the cron line gets too large, I always put it into a script.  This is definitely over that limit :-)

Comment: Thanks roaima and @stephen-harris. I actually did start off with a PHP script but the backed up file is heavy, just under 4gb. The script failed, never completed the task. Whereas it works fine on every other site I backup. Hence why I moved to a cron comand-line solution. I'll try the suggested single cron line tonight and report back. ;)

Comment: Okay as a follow up, this didn't work as expected. It did the backup, but no email was received, not in Spam folder either. Any ideas? Perhaps the command is just too long now...

Comment: Please replace `$USER` (`root` in my current edit) with your local username and see if that delivers.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try this tonight. Could I also use any email instead of "root"?

Comment: You can replace `root` with any local username.

Comment: Well no unfortunately, this didn't send an email. I checked the default account too. Nothing. I'll go back to the longer version for now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it with just `root` first? What is output of `ls -l /var/mail`? If you see non-zero-length files in there those are your _local_ mailboxes. You can see the messages either with `less` (or `more`) or more correctly with either `mail` or `mailx`.